# The best way to use python as a server scripting language for use on localhost

Tags: python, localhost, xampp

relatively long-time PHP user here. I could install XAMPP in my sleep at this point to the point where I can get a PHP script running in the browser at "localhost", but in my searches to find a similar path using Python, I've run out of Googling ideas. I've discovered the mod_python Apache mod, but then I also discovered that it's been discontinued. I'd greatly prefer to do my Python learning in a browser as opposed to the command prompt, so if anybody could point me along the proper path, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well mod_python has been retired.  So in order to host python apps you want `mod_wsgi`

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/

But python isn't really like php(as in you mix it with html to get output, if I understand your question correctly). In learning python, using the command line/repl will probably be much more useful/straight forward I would think.  If you are looking for python as primarily web development you should look into django (http://www.djangoproject.com/) as that might be closer to what you are looking for..

Comment: Thanks! I will give this all a good look. Thanks also to the other commenters!

Answer (score 4):

Most Python webframeworks have a built-in minimal development server:

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/)
- [Turbogears](http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/QuickStart.html#run-the-server)
- [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-ipaddr-port)
- [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/gettingstarted/#running-the-application)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en#start)
- [web2py](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/03)

But don't be afraid of the command line. Python has a great interactive console (just run `python`) and there's an even better one: [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/).

Answer (score 2):

Many options, here are a couple:

- [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is an Apache module that is suitable for production environments
- [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) ships with Python and is easy to use
- frameworks like [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)